# Is there a spell that a Cleric can learn that turns water in to a Water Elemental?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

In my first ever 3.5e game, the DM gave me a Cleric with a spell fitting this description. I've never found it since. Is it in any published 3.5e materials? Or was it probably homebrew? The Cleric was very low level, but I couldn't put a number on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Spell Compendium* has a 1st-level **druid** spell, *animate water*, which turns a quantity of water into a Small water elemental.

*Oriental Adventures* put the spell in the River domain, but *Oriental Adventures* doesn’t have clerics and its domains were for its shaman class; it’s not super clear whether or not clerics can use those domains in games that utilize both *Oriental Adventures* and non-*OA* classes.

But most likely what your DM did is just houserule that this is a cleric spell, or something available to your cleric, in particular, due to circumstances in the campaign.

There is also the Water Devotion feat from *Complete Champion*, which allows a someone to pour a waterskin out and get a water elemental. Anyone can take this feat, but a cleric can get it as a bonus feat and since (pre-errata) turn undead fuels its usage (errata removed the ability to use turn undead for it, making the feat worthless), cleric is well positioned to make the best use of it. Anyway, this is somewhat less likely as an answer because it’s a feat, not a spell.

Comment: By way of comparison, the feat Water Devotion (*Complete Champion* 64) lets even a normal cleric 1/day summon a water elemental using some water. (Ignore the errata and it's one of the best devotion feats, don't and no one takes it—there must be a compromise!)